# ASP.NET Razor - Binding multiple properties and forms in one PageModel

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, razor-pages

I'm very new to working in Microsoft Visual Studio and I set up a new Razor Web Application following the documentation and now I want to combine some of the actions that are broken apart on several pages.

For instance I want to use on PageModel for a "Sign Up" view, a "Sign In" view and a "Forgot Password" view but when trying to combine all "OnPostAsync" methods (using page-handlers and different names) the forms interfere with each other and the ModelState is always invalid.

I am also trying to combine the "Change Password" view with the "Update Profile" view and again, I am having the same issue.

Is it not possible to achieve something like this using Razor? It doesn't seem likely for that to be true.

Comment: The first issue of the forms can be resolved, but you need to share your code so that we can see what's wrong with it. The answer for the second question is no, it is possible to achieve such a thing using Razor Pages. Again please share your code so that we can help.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to post multiple different forms to the same page, but it is not recommended unless they all share the same model. Otherwise, as you seem to have found, things like a property which is `[Required]` for one form but not another will cause validation problems.

If you have to start compromising on the design of your PageModel to accommodate multiple forms, that should be a sign that you really need separate pages for the forms. Any benefit you might gain by reducing duplication in UI is being lost through additional complexity with validation etc.

Comment: It just seems a little weird that I cant use one Page Model for multiple Post functions. Unless maybe there is some misunderstanding here?

Either way, I found a workaround by using a nested _Layout for these specific Page Models I wanted to combine.

Comment: As I said, you _can_ post multiple forms to the same page. And they can share the same PageModel. Your question is general and I provided a general answer. If you have a specific issue with something you are trying to do, you should post some code so that others can replicate the issue and provide some guidance.